# Mongodb status shows failed even if it's running correctly

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, daemon

I have upgraded mongodb from v3.4 to v3.6 on ubuntu 16.04.

I can access to database using mongo shell or using robomongo.

But when I try to show the status of mongod it displays: `failed`

for both:

```
sudo service mongod status
```

and

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: I have uninstalled all files related to mongodb and install it again. after that I run `sudo systemctl enable mongod` . now it works !

Comment: You can answer your own question...

Comment: Kindly mark it right as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have uninstalled all files related to mongodb and install it again.

after that I run `sudo systemctl enable mongod` .

now it works !